# CKEditor 5 not working in production build angular 6

Tags: angular, ckeditor

I have implemented CKEditor 5 in my angular project. It is working fine when `ng serve`. But when I build production `ng build --prod` and deploy on server, it gives error and weird triangles appear in the editor  itself. I tried `ng build` to test the build on local machine. It works. Only the production build is not working.

Error:
[image: error]

ts file:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import * as ClassicEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic';
import { FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { WriterService } from '../../writer.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sample-new',
  templateUrl: './sample-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sample-new.component.css']
})
export class SampleNewComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('myEditor') myEditor: any;
  constructor(public writerService: WriterService, public router: Router) { }

  public Editor = ClassicEditor;
  sampleHtml = '';
  sampleForm: FormGroup;

  //toolbar options
  // ["undo", "redo", "bold", "italic", "blockQuote", "ckfinder", "imageTextAlternative", "imageUpload", "heading", "imageStyle:full", "imageStyle:side", "link", "numberedList", "bulletedList", "mediaEmbed", "insertTable", "tableColumn", "tableRow", "mergeTableCells"]

  config = {
    toolbar: ['heading', '|', 'bold', 'italic', "blockQuote", "numberedList", "bulletedList", "|", 'undo', 'redo']
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.sampleForm = new FormGroup({
      title: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }),
      content: new FormControl(null, {
        validators: [Validators.required]
      }
      )
    });
  }

  onSampleSubmit() {
    if (this.sampleForm.valid) {
      // console.log(this.sampleForm.value);
      this.sampleForm.value.content = encodeURI(this.sampleForm.value.content);
      // console.log(this.sampleForm.value);
      this.writerService.addSample(this.sampleForm.value).subscribe(
        response => {
          console.log("form submitted");
          this.sampleForm.reset();
          this.router.navigate(['/writer/portfolio']);
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

}

html file:

```
   <div class="container-md">
  <h2 class="mb-3">Add Sample</h2>
  <form (submit)="onSampleSubmit()" [formGroup]="sampleForm">
    <h4>Title:</h4>
    <input type="text" class="form-control mb-3" formControlName="title" required>
    <h4>Sample Content:</h4>
    <ckeditor #myEditor [editor]="Editor" [config]="config" formControlName="content" required></ckeditor>
    <button class="btn btn-success mt-3 mr-2" type="submit">Save</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary mt-3" routerLink="/writer/portfolio">Cancel</button>
  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem days ago. I tried to do many things and anyone of them solved my problem. The ckeditor was working normally in my machine, but when I published it into azure instance, the weird triangles appeared. I solved my problem bulding a custom ckeditor version, after that I put it into asset folder and changed the editor reference in the component import line point to my custom package

Try to build a custom ckeditor through the URL below

https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder

After that change the Editor path in your component adding the code below:

```
import * as Editor from '../../../assets/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js';
```

hope it comes in the right time